# ColdFusion Sybase data source configuration error

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to configure a Sybase datas source in ColdFusion Administrator. I am getting the following error message when verifying the connection:
Connection verification failed for data source: IntellicredClient
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][Sybase JDBC Driver]No more data available to read.
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][Sybase JDBC Driver]No more data available to read.

The only probably issue I can think of is the driver I choose. When I'm connecting to the database manually, I use Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0 or SQL Anywhere 11. Since there's no such a choice in the Administrator, I choose Sybase. Could this be the problem?

I have ColdFusion 11.

Comment: Is your licence a standard or enterprise one (that said, I dunno what the licensing restrictions on Sybase are with CF). Have you tried a third-party JDBC driver with a DSN type of "other"?

Comment: I tried setting JDBC URL as jdbc:sqlanywhere:DSN=My Dsn, plus user name and password for "other", but got "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver available for intellicredJDBC" error. I left driver class and driver name empty. Can you let me know how to find these information to fill in?

Comment: Well did you *look in the docs*? They're free and online. Did you google? Did you do *anything* to try to answer your own question here?

Comment: I was hoping to have guideline of how to find exact information in my environment, somewhere on my local PC or database server etc. But to answer your question, yes, I've found some articles about JDBC connection strings and have tried the following but all are getting same "no suitable driver" error.

Comment: (to continue) JDBC URL: jdbc:sybase:Tds:MyHost:MyPort (with or without ServiceName or database name). 
Driver class: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver and com.sybase.jdbc.SybDriver.

Comment: Pls update the question with this information, rather than put it in comments (ppl are likely to miss it down here). It doesn't sound like you actually have the driver you're trying to use installed?

Comment: Yes. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29221445/edit) to include the *exact* DSN settings you tried, (cAsE matters). *RE: It doesn't sound like you actually have the driver you're trying to use installed*  Specifically 1) Did you add the jdbc driver jar that you want to use to the CF class path first? 2) If so, did you restart the CF server afterward? Both are common causes of the "No suitable driver available" error.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bug in the JDBC driver. Try replacing current JDBC drivers with the older and stable version. View the link below for instructions.

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4165262